# How to set negative time difference value to zero

Tags: mysql

If time difference result is negative how do i set it to zero

```
select TIMEDIFF('2016-01-29 12:28:18','2016-01-29 19:27:51') as diff;
```

---

| -06:59:33 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select if((time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF('2016-01-29 12:28:18','2016-01-29 19:27:51'))/3600) < 0,0,TIMEDIFF('2016-01-29 12:28:18','2016-01-29 19:27:51')) as diff;
```